Portainer Oauth using Authentik 404 Error on token URL
I'm trying to use Authentik as an SSO provider for Portainer in my local development environment. Both are hosted as containers on my local Docker Desktop and exposed locally on http://localhost:9000 and https://localhost:9444 respectively.
I have set up Authentik and Portainer according to the documentation provided by Authentik, see below images. I have also enabled automatic user provisioing in the OAuth settings of Portainer.
Authentik Provider Settings

Portainer settings

Now when I go to my Portainer instance and press Login with OAuth button I am redirected to Authentik. I log in to Authentik and give consent to the authorization request from Portainer. I am then redirected to the Portainer and Portainer displays the error Unauthorized.
I have enabled Debug level logging for portainer and it shows the following chain of messages.
2024-04-17 15:33:40 2024/04/17 01:33PM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/oauth/oauth.go:34 > failed retrieving oauth token | error="oauth2: cannot fetch token: 404 Not Found\nResponse: 404 page not found\n"
2024-04-17 15:33:40 2024/04/17 01:33PM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/handler/auth/authenticate_oauth.go:76 > OAuth authentication error | error="oauth2: cannot fetch token: 404 Not Found\nResponse: 404 page not found\n"
2024-04-17 15:33:40 2024/04/17 01:33PM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/security/bouncer.go:401 > HTTP error | error=Unauthorized msg="Unable to authenticate through OAuth" status_code=500

It seems the token url at http://localhost:9000/application/o/token/ does not exist. As far as I can see I have correctly configured both applications but obviously something is going wrong.
